# Sharing GIF in Android

Tags: android, gif

I am working on an Android app wherein I have to implement functionality of sharing GIF with other messaging app.

For that I am storing in a temporary file and passing file's url through intent. My gif is stored as a drawable. Thus while retrieving it I used FileOutputStream with Bitmap.Compress. Due to this instead of GIF I am getting a stil image.

Also, I tried converting Bitmap to Byte Array without compressing, but in this case my image is not showing up

My code to share gif:

```
int drawableId = gridItemList.get(position);
Bitmap contentToShare = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),   drawableId);                
try {
    File cachePath=new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(),"content");
    cachePath.mkdirs();
    FileOutputStream stream=new FileOutputStream(cachePath+"/anim.gif");
    contentToShare.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    stream.close();
    File imagePath = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "content");
    File newFile = new File(imagePath,"anim.gif");
    Uri contentURI=FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),getPackageName()+".fileprovider",newFile);
    if(contentURI!=null)    {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentURI);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        shareIntent.setType("image/gif");
        startActivity(shareIntent);
    }
}catch (Exception e)    {
    Log.e("Exception",e.toString());
}
```

PS : Sharing jpeg and png is working perfectly.

Comment: post your code...

Comment: Use Glide library to show your GIF

Comment: I am already using glide to load gif from drawable. But I am not able to share gif

Answer (score -1):

Use Glide library to show your GIF

In Your Gradle:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

Code to write:

```
String gifUrl = "http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--B7tUiM5l--/gf2r69yorbdesguga10i.gif";

Glide  
    .with( context )
    .load( gifUrl )
    .into( imageViewGif );
```